# missing argument error not working

Tags: python

i have i simple question i hope. I have this simple list

```
pommes : 54
orange
bananes : 18
```

The program is actualy not working if my argv[1] is missing like in the case of the word orange. I have tried to raise an error with this fallowing code but it didnt work. Under this i have included my code.

```
if parts[1] == "":
    print("La ligne '", i, "' n'est pas correctement formaté.")
    sys.exit()
```

---

Here is my block of code that is working without the part i tried above.

```
for i in message:
    parts = i.split(":")
    gauche = parts[0].strip()
    droite = parts[1]
    try:
        if len(parts) != 2:
            print("La ligne '", i, "' n'est pas correctement formaté.")
            sys.exit()
        elif not gauche.isalpha():
            print("La ligne '", i, "' n'est pas correctement formaté.")
            sys.exit()
        droite = int(droite)
    except ValueError:
        print("La ligne '", i, "' n'est pas correctement formaté.")
        sys.exit()
```

Comment: You have to check `if len(parts)==2` __before__ you attempt to access the second part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check the parts[1] is exist or not before you assign parts[1] to droite `droite = parts[1]`, if the length of parts is 1, you cannot get the parts[1], there will be Exception raised: `IndexError: list index out of range`.

Below is fix based on your code:

```
for i in message:
parts = i.split(":")
gauche = parts[0].strip()   
droite = parts[1] if len(parts)==2 else 0 # set the default value to 0
try:
    if len(parts) != 2:
        print("La ligne '", i, "' n'est pas correctement formaté.")
        sys.exit()
    elif not gauche.isalpha():
        print("La ligne '", i, "' n'est pas correctement formaté.")
        sys.exit()
    droite = int(droite)
except ValueError:
    print("La ligne '", i, "' n'est pas correctement formaté.")
    sys.exit()
```

Btw, the Exception you raised in your code, it will only raise if Exception is ValueError.